# How to get Context Group name in Talend

Tags: talend

As per my requirement i have added 2 context groups in my job. Below is the screenshot of my job:

[image]

Context group names are DBConnection and SourceConnection.

My requirement is to get those group names and display on console. Is there any way to get Only context group names in Talend?

Please help me.

Thanks,
Divya

Comment: There is no option to get context group name.You can do one thing, create a new context group having context group name and call it via context variables

Answer (score 0):

Use a tContextDump and output to tLogRow and you will have your context variables printed to console.

Comment: This does not give the context group name (DBConnection and SourceConnection), which is what the OP is looking for I believe.

Comment: As far as I know there is no way to retrieve those, only the context variables.

Comment: Yes I need only context group names ibrahim